# Code isn't working, trying to get image to show

Tags: java, image, swing, embedded-resource

I don't really understand why my code doesn't work to show this picture of a cow, any suggestions? I did everything correctly from my information. So I am not quite sure what went wrong. I use eclipse and the program shows no error. So if anyone can help it would be really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
    package Zeus;

import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;


public class Main extends JFrame{

    public static final int WIDTH = 400;
    public static final int HEIGHT = 300;
    public static final int SCALE = 2;

    private ImageIcon COW;
    private static JLabel C0W;

    Main() {
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        COW = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Cow Clicker/Resource/COW.png"));
        C0W = new JLabel(COW);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame Squishy = new JFrame("Squishy");
        Squishy.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Squishy.setResizable(false);
        Squishy.setVisible(true);
        Squishy.setSize(WIDTH*SCALE, HEIGHT*SCALE);
        Squishy.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        Squishy.add(C0W);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to create an instance of `Main` so that the image can be loaded from its constructor.

Comment: 1+. That's crazy code up there.

Comment: sure is, will rustle up some alternative code, already done by nachokk, nvm...

Comment: it was difficult where to start, but you get the point :D +1

Answer (score 1):

I don't know where to start

1st) Variables in java by convention starts with lower case following a camel-style.
So your variables `COW` should be changed to `cow` and so on.

2nd)IMHO  i never use variables names like `C0W`.

3rd) You are extending `JFrame` without any reason, so change your code to this.

```
public class Main{

    public static final int WIDTH = 400;
    public static final int HEIGHT = 300;
    public static final int SCALE = 2;
    private JFrame frame;
    private ImageIcon cow;
    private JLabel labelCow; // remove static

    public Main() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setSize(WIDTH*SCALE, HEIGHT*SCALE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        cow = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("Cow Clicker/Resource/COW.png"));
        labelCow = new JLabel(cow);
        frame.add(cow);
        //pack(); you are using setSize
        setVisible(true);
    }





    public static void main(String[] args) {
               SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
                     @Override
                     public void run(){
                         new Main();
                     }

                });
     }

}
```